# Can i force sharepoint online Office 365 to create the managed property for our site columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, office-365, managed-property, crawled-property

I have created a team site inside our sharepoint online office 365. and i have created many lists which contain site columns and the list already have data. but when i create a content result web part, and i checked the managed properties, i did not find any managed property representing the custom site columns i created. here is the managed property list i am talking about:-

[image]

now in sharepoint on-premises, i need to run a full crawl to create the related managed properties for the site columns. but now inside office 365 i have the list created around 30 hours ago,, but till now i can not find the related managed properties representing my custom site columns? so is there anything i can do to start showing the managed properties inside office 365? or i have to wait?

**EDIT** now as mentioned on @gachCoder reply i checked the Crawled Properties and the Managed properties on the Search inside office 365. and i find that both the crawl propert and the managed property are created as follow:-

1. **Crawl Property:-**

[image]

2. **Managed Property:-**

[image]

but i have noted the following:-

1. still the managed property is not showing inside the Search result web part menu.
2. and seems to me that the Managed property is grey out for a reason or another when i search for it from "Search>>Managed Properties" as shown in the above picture... i am not sure if this give any indication!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually it takes **72hrs. to one week**. Since its been 72hrs in your case. There are three options,

1. You can wait for a week.
2. You can try your luck with reindex list.
3. If you have Admin access on your O365, then you can check weather crawled property has been created or not. If crawled property has created then you can create manage property and map that crawled property with the same.

[image][image][image][image][image]

Parallely, you can raise a ticket for Microsoft regarding the same.

Comment: thanks for the reply .. can you check my edit please?

Comment: You can edit that greyed out property and set Searchable, Queryable, Retrievable as  Yes and map your crawled property as well.

Comment: now i was able to use the managed properties without modifying them... so seems there are already there... but still these managed properties are not showing inside the Search Result web part list. so the issue is not related to creating the managed properties,, but related that the managed properties list inside the content result web part is not being updated with the new managed properties...